# Add Version to Url Rules of Yii Rest API

Tags: php, yii

I have an REST API with Yii Framework based on:
http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/175/how-to-create-a-rest-api/

I would like to add a version of the API in the Url Rules, like:

```
array('api/view', 'pattern'=>'api/<version:\d+>/<model:\w+>/<id:\d+>', 'verb'=>'GET'),
```

How should I do that?

Comment: What is your actual problem? The rule is not working? Did you put your rule before the defaults ones in the array?

Comment: I dont know how to implement to add the version at the url, because I only have one controller named ApiController.php. How could I implement a version at the url redirecting to the right controller?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use one controller you could do keep the rule as you have done:

```
array('api/view', 'pattern'=>'api/<version:\d+>/<model:\w+>/<id:\d+>', 'verb'=>'GET'),
```

And in the controller Action check the version:

```
public function actionView()
{
    // Check the version
    if($_GET['version'] == 1)
    {
       //do what you've got to do
    }
    else if ($_GET['version'] == 2)
    {
       //do what you've got to do
    }
}
```

Another solution is to use [custom URL rule functionnality](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.url#using-custom-url-rule-classes)

- In the method "parseUrl" you check if the url is matching your rule
  (there is api/version/model/id) and if it is matching depending on the api version you redirect to the right controller (ex: apiV2/view)

Code:

```
public function parseUrl($manager,$request,$pathInfo,$rawPathInfo)
{
   if (preg_match('%^(api/(\d+))(/(\w+))(/(\d+))$%', $pathInfo, $matches))
        {
            // $matches[2] is the version and $matches[4] the model
            // If it matches we can check the version api and the model
            // If it's ok, set $_GET['model'] and/or $_GET['id']
            // and return 'apiVx/view'
        }
        return false;  // this rule does not apply
    }
```

Comment: To get a cleaner code, would be better to separate versions into different controllers. There is how to code an 'intermediary' to pass to the right controller?

Comment: I updated my answer with an other solution.

I understand it could be better to have different controllers depending on the version, after id depends if the code is a lot different or not between the 2 versions!

Comment: No problem! If the answer solves your problem you should accept the answer by clicking on the tick!

Answer (score 1):

Put the entire API into a module, the versions into sub-modules, and include them in the main module configuration:

```
/api    -> modules.ApiModule
/api/v1 -> modules.ApiModule.modules.V1Module
/api/v2 -> modules.ApiModule.modules.V2Module
```

... etc...

I think the path version of the default Yii router supports this pattern automatically, but I might be wrong. In any case, organizing the versions into modules allows them to easily share code while still remaining distinct, and makes error rendering back to the user natural.